# Image component doesn't go well with animation

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, animation

I have a volume button with Image component, and also I have a settings button, when I press my settings button the OpeningSettings Animation starts, then, when I press a volume button, it changes its Image.sprite and ClosingSettings Animation ignores the Image.color of the Volume button, how do I need to fix it? Here's code that changes the sprite of the Volume button

```
transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = VolumeOnImg;
```

[image: How it works]
[image: How it should work]

Comment: Does your animator anywhere have a KeyFrame on that color property? If so then the animator has control over it and basically nothing else can change the color as the animator is almost the last thing executed before a frame is rendered ...

Comment: My animator is changing color, while my script is changing sprite, but when sprite is changed by the script, the animator changes color in the inspector, but in the game there is no changes

Comment: Could you show some screens of what is happening vs what is supposed/you would expect to happen?

Comment: What's more interesting that if sprite changed by script before animation has started, everything works fine

Comment: @derHugo The first screenshot is showing how it should not work and the second one is showing the correct example of working

Comment: If I change sprite firstly through script and then I do the same in the inspector, the animation will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I just remade the system. Instead of changing sprites, I made two gameObjects for sound on and sound off and just turn on or turn off them through script